# You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/

Tags: gatsby

when i tried to build gatsby build got this error
failed Compiling Gatsby Functions - 6.195s

Failed to validate error [Error [ValidationError]: "error" must be of type object] {

_original: {

```
context: {},

error: [

  ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (99:8)

  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See
```

https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
  |

  |       const HeadElement = (

  >         <pageComponent.Head {...filterHeadProps(pageComponentProps)} />

  |       )

  |

      at handleParseError (/home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:982:19)

      at /home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:1101:5

      at processResult (/home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:806:11)

      at /home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:866:5

      at /home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:407:3

      at iterateNormalLoaders (/home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:10)

      at /home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:224:4

      at /home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:840:15

      at Array.eval (eval at create (/home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:12:1)

      at runCallbacks (/home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:43:15)

      at /home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:249:5

      at /home/deskweb/Documents/auth-ui/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16

      at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3),

  ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (108:13)

  You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See
```

https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

```
  |     // eslint-disable-next-line

  |     if (!this.state.page) {

  >       return <div />

  |     }
```